# C++11 about *begin(a)

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

```
#include<iterator>
#include<iostream>

int a[5][4];

int main()
{
    cout << *begin(a);
}
```

Why does this `cout` print the same as `begin(a)`?

It seems the `*` does not dereference the pointer returned by `begin(a)`?

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: This doesn't look like compilimg C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here `*` affects only the type of the pointer, and not its numerical value.

`std::begin(a)` returns a pointer to the first element of `a`, of type `int (*)[4]` (pointer to an array of 4 ints).

`*std::begin(a)` returns `int[4]`. Since `cout` can't print arrays directly, the array then decays to the pointer to its first element, of type `int *`, and is printed as such.

`**std::begin(a)` would return an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a two-dimensional array

```
int a[5][4];
```

Its elements in turn one-dimensional arrays of the type `int[4]`.

The expression `*begin( a )` yields a reference to the first element of the array of the type `int ( & )[4]`. Used in this statement

```
 cout << *begin(a);
```

the expression is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `int *` and equivalent to `&a[0][0]`.

On the other hand the expression `begin( a )` has the type `int ( * )[4]`.

The address of the whole two-dimensional array coincides with the address of its first element, one dimensional array, that in turn coincides with the address of the first element of the one-dimensional array. though the used expressions have different types.

Comment: Obligatory "expressions can't have reference types". :P

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The comment has nothing common with my answer.

Comment: `*begin( a )` is an expression, and as such, can't have type `int ( & )[4]`. It's an lvalue of type `int[4]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  In my answer there is written that the expression yields a reference.

Comment: I know? I'm arguing that it's not the case. See http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#2

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Try std::cout << std::is_same_v< decltype( *std::begin( a ) ), int( & )[4] > << '\n';

Comment: When applied to an expression (as opposed to a variable), `decltype` doesn't always yield its actual type: it may add reference-ness to the actual type to indicate the value category of the expression (for lvalues it adds `&`). See (2) here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It is the return type of the overloaded operator * for iterators. The operator returns an lvalue reference.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sub#2 says that when `[]` is applied to `T[N]` or `T *`, the result has type `T`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat As I pointed to the overloaded operator return lvalue reference.